# I am not able to get windows boot option after installing centos 7 in dual boot. My windows is windows 10

Tags: centos, windows

I have tried a few things .

### The output of fdisk-l is:

```
[root@localhost mohit_dubey]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       206847    100M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       206848       411647    100M  Microsoft basic 
 3       411648    409372671    195G  Linux LVM       
 4    409372672    451315711     20G  Microsoft basic 

Disk /dev/sdb: 8076 MB, 8076132352 bytes, 15773696 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x13f6b0ea

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sdb1   *        2048    15773695     7885824    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 207.2 GB, 207232172032 bytes, 404750336 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

---

### the output of grub2-mkconfig > /dev/null:

```
[root@localhost mohit_dubey]# grub2-mkconfig > /dev/null
/usr/bin/grub2-editenv: error: cannot open `/boot/grub2/grubenv.new': No space     left on device.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.img
```

### done

NO windows listed.

Comment: Did you create that (seemingly small) EFI partition when installing CentOS, or was it already there? Unless I'm wrong, EFI partitions are shared by OSes, and you could have erased the Windows entries by overwriting the partition.

Comment: I created the efi manually.What do i do next my very important data is at risk

Comment: Can you please help me out how to get my windows entry back.

Comment: In CentOS, create a mount point : `mkdir /mnt/windows`, mount the Windows partition to it : `mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/windows`, and get your files from `/mnt/windows`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a pro in Redhat-based linuxes, but in Debian and Arch you need to install a package called `os-prober` and recreate Grub config afterwards.